# Phone will not let me ENCRYPT

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, encryption

I want to encrypt my apps and personal data, such as passwords to email etc.

If I have factory reset my phone (GS2sprint) and it is fully charged (over 90%) and plugged in. So I went to *Settings→Apps→Security*, and from there to *Encrypt* or *Encrypt SDCard* -- but it won't let me encrypt: The buttons are grayed out.

Why won't it let me encrypt? I have a new file that I have not seen before which is sprint extention. It will not let me stop it and like I said after Hard Factory reset it still will not let me encrypt anything.

Comment: I updated your question accordingly, JAY. Please do the same with the following details: What kind of lock-screen security have you set up -- PIN, password, pattern, or none? AFAIR encryption does not accept one of them. You might want to read [How to Encrypt Your Android Phone and Why You Might Want To](http://www.howtogeek.com/141953/how-to-encrypt-your-android-phone-and-why-you-might-want-to/) -- which says it must be either PIN or password set up before you can encrypt.

Comment: I've set up a pin for my lock screen.

Comment: To get it right: You've set up a PIN and now it works -- or you already had set up a PIN and it still does not work?

Comment: Mr Izzy one more question. Ive tried what you said and Ive put in a password with numbers and this dang phone still wont encrypt its data. It factory resets its self with a error mssg that reads interuption when there should be none because it is over its percent to start encryption and its plugged in. Then I did the only encrypt data on phone or short encryption and I still have the same mssg... Encryption failed due to interuption omg! He is coming

Comment: Sorry, then I'm lost, too... Who's coming? Where to? [locking my door, just in case...]

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to this discussion, but, for others out there that may have not gotten an answer to this yet, device encryption on some devices may only work with a strong password. A (medium security) PIN may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You already have to have a strong password selected and installed and then the encryption button will be available for you to press.

Answer (score 0):

The Android phone must be fully charged (100%) and charging in order to encrypt your phone. The button will change dark when your phone is fully charged and charging. There is now a notification text about the thing in the Android 6.x. It also says that the encryption may take one hour and more.